# Bootstrap sticky element not stick

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I made a simple sticky element via `css` but I'm using Bootstrap, if I include BS, sticky not work but if remove, it work fine, why? any idea?

```
.navbar {
  background: hotpink;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

**[Sticky without Bootstrap](http://jsfiddle.net/pwq869f3/)**

**[Sticky with Bootstrap](http://jsfiddle.net/pwq869f3/1/)**

Comment: Is it bootstrap 3 or 4? Your tags include both. Which browser are you using? Sticky is not supported very well, you may want to try *position: fixed;*

Comment: In the fiddle, you include Bootstrap after your own styles, so Bootstrap overrides them. Do it in the proper way - http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/pwq869f3/5/ - and it will work as designed.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's stylesheet is being applied after your custom styles an is overriding your declaration of `position: sticky` to `position: relative`.

You have two options.

1) Ensure your stylesheet is loaded after bootstrap's

2) Write a more specific selector eg `body .navbar`